# list with case class scala

Tags: scala, case-class

I have the following issue I have the following  list as input

```
val input:List[Item]=List(FRDVE,12
SDED,13
prog-d,11
PROG-D,15
a-prog-d,17)
```

with

```
case class Item(Name:String,Number:Int)
```

The aim is to find only first line where name contains either prog-d or PROG-D

so for this case the expected output is:

```
val output="prog-d"
```

I wrote the following code :

```
def getName(input:List[Item]):Option[String]={
    val matchLine=input.filter(Name.contains("prog-d"))
    matchLine  match {
      case head::tail => Some(matchLine.head.split(",")(0))
      case isEmpty => None
    }

  }
```

so here I am getting an error saying that the Name doesn't exist and I don't know how to put different possibilities in the contains : here it should basically  be : `Name.contains("prog-d" ||"PROG-D")`
Any recommendations please 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `find` where this function returns the option of first elements whichever matches your condition (stops iterating on remaining elements).

```
case class Item(Name:String,Number:Int)
    val input = List(Item("FRDVE",12), Item("SDED",13), Item("prog-d",11), Item("PROG-D",15), Item("a-prog-d",17))
    input.find(_.Name.equalsIgnoreCase("prog-d")) match {
      case Some(item)  => item.Name
      case None => "" //your default string
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure if this works if I had "fds-prog-d" , we should rather use contains, startsWith,endsWith rather; may you confirm this

Comment: It won't work when `equalsIgnoreCase` is used. You can use `contains` to make a match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collectFirst`:

```
input.collectFirst { case Item(s, _) if s.equalsIgnoreCase("prog-d") => s }
```

This avoids both `map` and `filter`, so that only the minimal necessary amount of entries is inspected.

Full code:

```
case class Item(name: String, number: Int)

val input: List[Item] = List(
  Item("FRDVE", 12),
  Item("SDED", 13),
  Item("prog-d", 11),
  Item("PROG-D", 15),
  Item("a-prog-d", 17),
)

val output = input.collectFirst {
  case Item(s, _) if s.equalsIgnoreCase("prog-d") => s
}

println(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `item.Name == "prog-d" || item.Name == "PROG-D"` or `item.Name.equalsIgnoreCase("prog-d")`

```
scala> val input = List(Item("FRDVE",12), Item("SDED",13), Item("prog-d",11), Item("PROG-D",15), Item("a-prog-d",17))
input: List[Item] = List(Item(FRDVE,12), Item(SDED,13), Item(prog-d,11), Item(PROG-D,15), Item(a-prog-d,17))

scala> input.filter(item => item.Name.equalsIgnoreCase("prog-d")).map(_.Name)
res1: List[String] = List(prog-d, PROG-D)
```

If you want the first match, do `headOption` and play with it based on what data you want.

```
scala> val output = input.filter(item => item.Name.equalsIgnoreCase("prog-d")).headOption
output: Option[Item] = Some(Item(prog-d,11))

scala> val outputName = input.filter(item => item.Name.equalsIgnoreCase("prog-d")).headOption.map(_.Name)
outputName: Option[String] = Some(prog-d)
```

**NOTE:** *(`.head` is not safe to use because `List().head` will explode when list is empty)*

```
scala> List.empty[Item].head
java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
  at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:428)
  at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:425)
  ... 28 elided
```

Comment: if I just want to take one element should I add .head

Comment: @scalacode use `headOption` instead which is safer way.